# Daily style site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm working on a daily style site. I found one site that does what I want and am wondering about the best way to do it.

I thought about having a PHP file that simply spits out a saying based on date(z) from PHP. O use a database because it's probably better practice.

What do you think? Here is the site I'm trying to emulate, you can get some idea from viewing the source, but the saying changes daily: http://daily-day.com/.

Just some suggestions in the right direction would be great. I don't want you to write it for me. As a beginner I want to do it myself with a little help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a MySQL table to store quotes, and recall them using PHP.
You could recall them based on date, or you might be able to do something where is selects the  most recent quote (by id), that hasn't been requested yet. So maybe you would have a value called 'requested' and if it is 0, it hasn't been displayed. Then when you select it via MySQL_query(); you change the value to 1.

Comment: this looks like it might be the best answer. I'll try this out now

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complex with that javascript thingy. You can just output the text from PHP.
You could use an array, but that means you have to add new proverbs to your code.

A database table would be just as easy. You need just a single table with a data and a text column. You can enter new proverbs for each day beforehand and just query the one for the current date.

It allows you to retrieve every line you have used so far, so you can add a 'browse history' feature later.

There are numerous MySQL examples for PHP. This is about as close as you'll get to the Hello World of databases. :)

Comment: cool thanks. So db might be the way to go. Maybe I'll try that first and then do the other one next for practice... looking forward to trying this

Answer (score 1):

I've done these things before and it depends on how many sayings you have. If you have 5 rotating sayings for a  month:

```
<?php

 $sayings = "one
             two
             three
             ";

 $sayings = split("\n",$things);

 $num = date("z") % count($sayings);

 echo $sayings[$num];

?>
```

Or something like that could do the trick. But Trufa is right, if you want to know about CSS layout or something you're asking too broad a question. I don't think that is the case though.

Comment: wow much isimpler than what I was doing +1

Answer (score 0):

This is an overly broad question that does not have much to do with a Q&A site, please take a look at our FAQ.

To briefly answer toy question getting a simple database structure working for a relatively small site is not so complicated and would help you scale eventually, you've said it yourself it is better practice.

Just imagine having to change your PHP file every time you add a new phrase or want to add some functionality. You could brake it every time.

Implement a database and google around for a some scripts examples of what you are doing, there are a lot out there and it will help you as a learning exercise.

Comment: I disagree that this is too broad -1, but good answer.

Comment: @Zevan: I really don't care that much about reputation, but I wouldn't advice to use down-votes in that way since it may keep good answers (you said that not me :) ) in the further down, IMHO down-votes should be used when answers are clearly wrong or misleading in a programming sense, that said, you can use the down-votes in what ever way you feel is correct, this is just a suggestion for future occasions.

Comment: thanks trufa I think you are right actually. good point